# Дополнительная настройка ОС при запуске удалённой отладки через idea

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, ssh, remote-debugging

Пробую настроить удалённую отладку через SSH java приложения с GUI через Intellij IDEA.
Всё успешно подключается, загружается и запускается, однако после запуска приложение падает с ошибкой:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
```

Как я понимаю перед запуском в той же сессии SHH, которую открывает IDEA при запуске удаленной отладки мне нужно выполнить команду

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Однако нигде не могу найти настройку, которая бы выполнила данную команду перед запуском приложения.  Как мне заставить IDEA выполнить команду export?

Если вручную загружать и запускать приложение через SSH то всё работает и корректно запускается (после выполнения команды `export DISPLAY=:0`)

Целевая машина на которой запускается приложение: Debian

Машина на которой ведётся отладка: Windows 10

Используемая версия java: 17

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Это называется переменные окружения (environment variables). Они задаются в `Run Configuration` в поле `Environment Variables`. Смотрите https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html#host_rc